# optirun No - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "void"

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, xorg

I get this wierd error when I'm trying to run (for example) `optirun -vv glxspheres`. I had it working a couple of days ago, but now it just wont start.

```
    [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
    [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modinfo started, PID 8452.
    [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modinfo
    [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
    [DEBUG]Detected nvidia driver (module nvidia-current)
    [DEBUG]Active configuration:
    [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
    [DEBUG] X display: :8
    [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
    [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
    [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
    [DEBUG]optirun version 3.0 starting...
    [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "void" (module does not exist, 0)

    [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "void" (module does not exist, 0)

    [DEBUG]Socket closed.
    [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
    [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

**Some background info:**
I'm running a wubi (11.10) install on an ASUS UL30VT. The only thing I really did since the last time optirun was working, was using windows. Previously I changed `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` to allow me to use the HDMI port. But that doesn't seem to be the problem. I looked everywhere to find someone with a similar error, but with no luck.

The output from `lspci | grep -i vga` is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210M] (rev a2)
```

And from `sudo cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` is

```
0000:01:00.0 ON
```

Here's my `xorg.conf.nvidia`:

```
    Section "DRI"
            Mode 0666
    EndSection

    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier  "Layout0"
        Option  "AutoAddDevices" "false"
        Screen  "Screen0"
        InputDevice "void-mouse"
        Option      "Xinerama" "0"
    EndSection

    Section "Module"
            Load  "dbe"
            Load  "extmod"
            Load  "glx"
            Load  "record"
            Load  "freetype"
            Load  "type1"
    EndSection

    Section "Files"
        ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Device1"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName   "GeForce G 210M"
        BusID   "01:00:0"
        Option  "NoLogo" "true"
        Option  "UseEDID" "true"
        Option      "IgnoreEDID"
        Option  "ConnectedMonitor" "DP1"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier   "Screen0"
        Device       "Device1"
        DefaultDepth 24
        Monitor      "DP1"
        Option       "TwinView" "0"
        Option       "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0; 1680x1050 +0+0; 1440x900 +0+0; 1280x1024 +0+0; 1366x768 +0+0; 1360x768 +0+0; 1280x800 +0+0; 1024x768 +0+0; 800x600 +0+0; 640x480 +0+0"
        Option       "FlatPanelProperties" "Scaling = Native"
        SubSection "Display"
            Depth 24
            Modes "1920x1200" "1920x1080" "1680x1050" "1600x1200" "1440x900" "1280x1024" "1366x768" "1360x768" "1280x800" "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
        EndSubSection
    EndSection

    Section "Extensions"
            Option "Composite" "Enable"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier  "DP1"
        VendorName  "Unknown"
        ModelName   "Unknown"
        HorizSync   31.0 - 82.0
        VertRefresh 48.0 - 85.0
        Option      "DPMS"
        Modeline    "1920x1200"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1680x1050"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1600x1200"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1440x900"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1366x768"   85.25  1366 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1280x800"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline    "1280x1024"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
        ModeLine    "1024x768" 94.500 1024 1072 1168 1376 768 769 772 808 +hsync +vsync
    EndSection

    Section "InputDevice"
      Identifier "void-mouse"
      Driver     "void"
    EndSection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: Xorg can't find the module `void`.

The place you're telling it to load is:

```
Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier "void-mouse"
  Driver     "void"
EndSection
```

Either you make xorg find the module or you remove it from xorg.conf.

- To install it on Debian: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-void`. Then you'll have to guarantee that Xorg is trying to find it in the appropriate place (see `ModulePath`).
- To remove the module from xorg.conf, try to just remove the section above and then also remove the following line from `Section "Server Layout"`:

  ```
  InputDevice "void-mouse"
  ```

PS: I'm not sure stackoverflow is the right place for this kind of question...